# FFMPEG .oma to .mp3 "Unsupported codec 5!" with a big file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, codec

I'm trying to convert a .OMA file to .MP3 but no success with a specific file.

If I try:

```
ffmpeg -i audio1.oma -f mp3 output.mp3
```

The file is converted successfully. The file audio1.oma is a **3 MB** file.

Full output:

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
[oma @ 0x7f8fc4000000] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, oma, from 'audio1.oma':
  Metadata:
    title           : Is This It
    artist          : The Strokes
    album           : Is This It
    genre           : Rock
    OMG_TRLDA       : 2001/01/01 00:00:00
    TLEN            : 153000
  Duration: 00:02:33.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
Output #0, mp3, to 'output.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TIT2            : Is This It
    TPE1            : The Strokes
    TALB            : Is This It
    TCON            : Rock
    OMG_TRLDA       : 2001/01/01 00:00:00
    TLEN            : 153000
    TSSE            : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=    2397kB time=00:02:33.35 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=37.2x    
video:0kB audio:2397kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.016094%
```

If I try the same with another .oma (**53 MB**) I'm getting the error:

> Unsupported codec 5! audio2.oma: Function not implemented

Full output:

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
[oma @ 0x7f8792000000] Unsupported codec 5!
audio2.OMA: Function not implemented
```

Both audios works fine when using the MP3 Player.
The first audio which works is just a random song from my MP3 player to test.
The second file was recorded in a music studio playing live with multiple channels.

Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Can you provide the file so we can attempt to duplicate the issue?

Comment: I'll try to host somewhere.

Comment: Just to be clear for who's trying to close this question. The .oma file isn't piracy, the audio recorded on this file is my personal audio from my old band 10 years ago and it's the last memory left that I'm trying to retrieve.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, follows the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y31ejq1i6qhshuk/dennox.oma?dl=0

Comment: I'm wondering if could be some bug with the codec but not sure yet

Comment: question updated.
Both audios works fine when using the MP3 Player.
The first audio which works is just a random song from my MP3 player to test.
The second file was recorded in a music studio playing live with multiple channels. Not sure which software they used there.

Comment: Done. When I get an update there I'll sync here.
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6272

Comment: Might it just be the DRM you're bumping up against?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but I'm able to convert any of the other files which are from well known bands. How a personal recording could be under DRM? thanks

Comment: DRM is the central "feature" of the OpenMG format. [A file created on one computer cannot be decoded on another](https://forum.dbpoweramp.com/showthread.php?7532-Sony-OMA-OMG-File-Conversion-Some-actual-facts). If you don't have the computer on which the file was originally created, you are out of luck I'm afraid. BTW, if you '[ping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)' a user, by in my case adding @AkselA to the comment, the user will be immediately notified of your response.